How to get ip address of application deployed to cloudhub and set it in IP Allowlist policie
I have two applications in the cloud hub. I want the second application to accept requests only from the IP address of the first application. I tried getting the first application IP by writing ping "application address" and then setting it in  IP Allowlist police of the second app. But it seems that IP is incorrect because the first app can't access the second one

What did you ping exactly? Depending on the host name you use you will get different results.

You can set a static IP to the first Cloudhub Application. From the UI you can set it using static IPs tab in Runtime manager.
In the second application you can apply IP Allowlist Policy using API manager and Auto discovery.

Adding context to Harshank Bansal answer:

You can setup static IPs per application only in CloudHub 1.0. In CloudHub 2.0 static IPs for outbound traffic are assigned to the Private Space and shared by all applications.
CloudHub 1.0 static IPs are only for public IPs of the worker. In private networks the IP will not be static. The static IP will be assigned to mule-worker-APPNAME.REGION.cloudhub.io. Read the CloudHub 1.0 Network Guide for more details.

